# Constructing $\sqrt{a}$ for a constructable $0\leq a\in\mathbb{R}$ - Compass and straightedge constructions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compass-and-straightedge construction of the square root of a given line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705/compass-and-straightedge-construction-of-the-square-root-of-a-given-line)

I wish to understand how to construct $\sqrt{a}$ for a constructable
$0\leq a\in\mathbb{R}$ , the book Abstract Algebra (by David Steven
Dummit, Richard M. Foote) offers (in pg. 532) the following:

construct the circle with diameter $1+a$ (looks like a straight line
with the point $a$ somewhere on the line and $1+a$ at the right
end of the line) and erect the perpendicular to the diameter from
the point $a$ (the point with distance $a$ from the leftmost point
on the line). Then $\sqrt{a}$ is the length of the perpendicular.

My question is why the length of the perpendicular is $\sqrt{a}$
? (I'm guessing that there's a theorem in geometry that I don't know
about that might help...)

Help is appreciated!

Comment: See in particular [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/708/14366) to the question @Tim found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is simple geometry (Pythagorean theorem):

Take the circle with diameter $a+1$. then the point $a$ is at distance $\frac{a-1}{2}$ from the circle's center. the radius is $\frac{a+1}{2}$. So the perpendicular satisfies $(\frac{a-1}{2})^2+x^2=(\frac{a+1}{2})^2$, thus $x=\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can show it without the Pythagorean theorem, in a more geometric but longer proof.

Let $[BA]$ be the segment of length $a$, $[AC]$ its prolongation of length 1, and $H$ in on the circle of diameter $[BC]$ such that $AH\perp BC$.

1. **Thee triangle $CHB$ is rectangle in $H$ :**

   Let $O$ be the centre of the circle. Since the triangles $COH$ and $BOH$ are isosceles, one $\angle OCH=\angle OHC$ and $\angle OBH=\angle OHB$. Therefore, $\angle CHB=\angle BCH + \angle CBH$. Since the sum of the angles of $CBH$ is $\pi$, one has $CBH=\pi/2$
2. **The triangles $CAH$ and $AHB$ are similar :**

   Each of them has two angles in common with the $CHB$, so they are both similar to it.
3. **End of the proof :**

   Since $CAH$ and $AHB$ are similar, $\frac{CA}{AH}=\frac{AH}{AB}$, or equivalently $AH^2=CA\cdot AB=1\cdot a$.

Note that a slight variation on this reasoning gives another construction.
If you consider the similar triangles $BHC$ and $HAC$, you have $\frac{HC}{BC}=\frac{AC}{HC}$, or $HC=\sqrt{BC\cdot AC}$. $[HC]$'s length is the square root of the circle's diameter.