# For any point outside of a circle, is there ever only one tangent to the circle that passes through the point?

Tags: circles

For any point outside of a circle, is there ever only one tangent to the circle that passes through the point? Are there ever more than two such tangents? (I cannot find the exact answer i need. My question does not involve any actual numbers and equations. I just need a direct answer if there is only one tangent to the circle that passes through the point and why/how...) Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891430/constructing-two-tangents-to-the-given-circle-from-the-point-a-not-on-it

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly two tangents.
[image: Example]