# Relation between sqrt and ratio in ruler and compass?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

The construction in most vote reply in [Compass-and-straightedge construction of the square root of a given line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705/compass-and-straightedge-construction-of-the-square-root-of-a-given-line) uses similar traingles and uses $$\frac{AC}{AD}=\frac{AD}{AB}$$ to compute square root.

It seems that if we know how to do ratios, it is a given that we can do sqrt (that is sqrt can be replaced by ratio) right? If this is correct then to what extent can sqrt replace division in ruler and compass construction?

Comment: At first sight it cannot. If you can do addition, subtraction, multiplication and square root, you cannot do division.

Comment: Is there a proof?

Comment: @Arul-What exactly do you mean by - "to what extent can sqrt replace division in ruler and compass construction?"

Comment: @Arul-Also why do you say - "that is sqrt can be replaced by ratio"?This is the application of similarity to find square root.

Comment: @Arul-You can also computer square root using rulers.To what extent you can find it depends in the least count of the ruler.

Comment: @tatan What I am trying to say is sqrt becomes evident when you equal two divides. Is there a comparable operation to get divide from sqrt?

Comment: @Arul-By equal two divides do you mean equal two ratios?

Comment: $\frac{ac}{ad} = \frac{ad}{ab}$