# Construct line segments of lengths $a/b$ and $\sqrt {a}$

Tags: geometric-construction

Given: 3 lines (longest one a, medium one b and unit 1)

How can you construct line segments of lengths $a/b$, $\sqrt {a}$ and $a/n$ with $n$ a positive integer?

Comment: What do you mean by "construct"? What I am allowed to do? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @M.Winter With straightedge and compass

Answer (score 3):

Here are ideas for the fractions $a/b$ and $a/n$:

[image]

Comment: Thnx! And how do you construct the root of a?

Comment: @Elce Please search the site before posting a question. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/708/415941) was found by just googling the question.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the other answer, for $\sqrt a$, you can proceed as follows. Note that $(a+1)^2 - (a-1)^2 = 4a$.

So: Start by constructing a line segment $L$ of length $a-1$, then use one end $O$ as the centre of a circle $C$ of radius $a+1$. Construct a perpendicular to $L$, let this meet the circle $C$ at $P$. Join $P$ to $O$. $OP$ has length $a+1$. You now have a right triangle with hypotenuse $a+1$ and one cathetus $a-1$, so the other cathetus is $2\sqrt a$. Bisect that to get $\sqrt a$.

Comment: uh, no? Those will have length $\sqrt{2}a$.

Comment: @Wojowu Fixed it.