# How I construct a segment $a^2$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The length of a segment is given. How can we construct a segment equal to the square of the given segment?

Comment: Hint: Use a Thales Theorem

Comment: Okey, but how do I construct a^2 if I have been given the length of "a".

Comment: Do you mean constructing with the given straight segment and a compass?

Comment: Yes I should construct it with a compass and a straight segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this construction. BTW, it can also be used to multiply $a$ times $b$:

[image]

The green lines are parallel. The blue lines are any two that form an angle. You need a unit length as well, of course.

Comment: What app did you use for the diagram?

Comment: But then this construction requires **two** line segments: one of length $\;a\;$ , the other one of length $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: That's what "You need a unit length as well, of course" meant. :)

Comment: The "app" I used was ... PowerPoint. :)

Comment: Also: see silverfish's comment on the question here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705/compass-and-straightedge-construction-of-the-square-root-of-a-given-line) to see why a unit length is necessary for the question even to make sense. (Also Isaac's answer to the same question.)

Answer (score 0):

Carry out the inversion of the point $1$ on the $x$-axis with respect to the circle of radius $a$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Revised attempt:

1) Construct a $\triangle DBC$ with :

$|DB|=1;$ $ \angle BDC =90°$; $|DC|=a$ .

2) Construct a right angle at $C$, with one leg $BC$.

The other leg of this angle intersects $BD$

at $A$, I.e $\angle BCA =90°$.

3) We have :

$|AD| \cdot 1 = a^2.$

Comment: John.Oops, you are right.My mistake!

Comment: John Hughes.Hopefully ok now. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Looks good! Note that your solution (like mine) requires that you have a unit length as well as the length $a$ (see DonAntonio's comment on my answer).

Comment: John Hughes.Thanks, also for pointing out Don Antonio's comment.

Comment: Could it be done without a given unit length?

Comment: Maxim.John Hughes' and Don Antonio's comment, you need a length a, and a unit length.My answer: Under 1) :construction of triangle DBC we use  Side, Angle,Side with lengths a,1, and angle 90°.ok?