# Construction of $\sqrt{ab}$ user ruler and compass

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Q. Given two line segments of length a and b.
Draw a line segment of length $\sqrt{ab}$ using a ruler and compass.

I didn't get any idea how to approach to the solution.

Comment: Lines have infinite length. You mean segments (or line segments).

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/708

Answer (score 1):

Let the base of the large triangle be $a+b$, and the height $h$. By similarity of the small triangles,

$$\frac ha=\frac bh$$ so that $$h=\sqrt{ab}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line of length $a+b$.  Construct the perpendicular line in the point they joint.  The semicircle over $a+b$ cuts that perpendicular.  Now the distance between that point and the joining point is $\sqrt{ab}$ due to Euclid.

Comment: If you don't mind , Can you show it analytically please??

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem, please.

Comment: The word "diameter" is maybe missing in "The semi-circle over"

Comment: Being not a native speaker of the English language: What is ambiguous in the phrase "semicircle over a line segment"?

Comment: Nothing ambiguous... Don't bother with my remark.

Comment: Thanks a lot, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Join segments of length a and length b together on the same line. Call where they join Point J. Call their Midpoint M. Construct a circle centered at M through either end point of a+b. Construct a line perpendicular to a+b through point J. Call where it intersects the circle point Q. The length of QJ is $\sqrt{ab}$ as proven elsewhere. These above constructions follow from Euclid's postulates I, III, SAS, and ASA. So the constructions should be valid in neutral geometry.

A related approach. Construct a rectangle having one sidelength a and one side length b. Find a square having the same area as the starting rectangle. The side length of thes square will be $\sqrt{ab}$.